# DataTable Print Button Formatting Column Headers

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the DataTables Print Button and I am having trouble getting both of the columns to print the same. I use the same button setup for both grids that I print, but one grid will leave the Column header as-is, and the other will stack them.

For example, instead of the column saying "First Middle," it will be "First\nMiddle."

```
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'print',
        className: 'printButtonDetailOnly',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible',
        },
        title: 'I stack, sad face'
        customize: function (win) {
            $(win.document.body)
        .css('font-size', '18pt');

            $(win.document.body).find('table')
                .addClass('compact')
                .css('font-size', 'inherit');
        },
    }
]
```

which leaves me with [a stacked column](https://gyazo.com/b14fd65ea33d880caa8a9ba804a57644)

That, compared to the other print button:

```
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'print',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible'
        },
        title: 'I do not stack! Yay!',
        customize: function (win) {
            $(win.document.body)
        .css('font-size', '18pt');

            $(win.document.body).find('table')
                .addClass('compact')
                .css('font-size', 'inherit');
        },
    }
]
```

which provides an [un-stacked column](https://gyazo.com/ec8193cfdb284a841988366c9523cb3f)

I've been kicking this around for a few days, looking into all the properties for the print button, but nothing seems to control this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was actually with the table being populated.

The table that was stacking was missing

```
class="nowrap"
```

as a part of it.

Comment: I am having issue while printing can you help me out please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776387/formatting-the-output-of-datatable-when-there-are-filters-around-it